# MYSQL, grouping with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables. Sample Data Query:
cmadjprice:

```
select symbol,close,timestamp from cmadjprice;
ABCD,815.9,2014-10-31
ABCD,808.85,2014-11-03
ABCD,797.4,2014-11-05
ABCD,776.55,2014-11-07
ABCD,800.85,2014-11-10
ABCD,808.9,2014-11-11
ABCD,826.8,2014-11-12
ABCD,856.45,2014-11-13
ABCD,856.65,2014-11-14
```

BB03 table output sample query

```
select symbol,enter_dt,enter_price,exit_dt,exit_price from bb03 ;
ABCD,2014-10-31,815.90,2018-07-27,1073.60
```

am looking for maximum closing price with same date.

```
select a.symbol, max(a.close) ,a.timestamp  from  cmadjprice a
inner join BB03 b on a.symbol = b.symbol
where a.timestamp between b.enter_dt and b.exit_dt
group by a.symbol,a.timestamp;
```

am not getting output? Please help on this
Expecting output

```
ABCD,2014-10-31,815.90,2018-07-27,1073.60,856.65,2014-11-14;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:
Note that this may return more than one record in case if the maximum close value appeared more than once throughout the sequence of timestamps related to a given symbol

```
select c.symbol, c.maxval, d.timestamp from 
(
select 
a.symbol, 
max(a.close) as maxval 
from  
cmadjprice a
inner join BB03 b 
on a.symbol = b.symbol 
where a.timestamp between b.enter_dt and b.exit_dt
group by a.symbol
) c
inner join
cmadjprice d
on c.symbol = d.symbol and c.maxval = d.close
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select a.symbol, max(cast(a.close as DECIMAL(5,2)))  from  cmadjprice a
inner join BB03 b on a.symbol = b.symbol
where a.timestamp between b.enter_dt and b.exit_dt
group by a.symbol;
```

Comment: am getting multiple rows. I am expecting ABCD,856.65,2014-11-14 this row from cmadjprice table

Comment: It is obvious that you get multiple rows because you use `group by` on symbol and timestamp which leads to having multiple records. btw check my updated query please.

Comment: if you expect only that row, why do you include timestamp into select? do groupby for symbol only and select the max close value

Comment: As per business requirements, i need close value and timestamp (the peak date for the close price)

Comment: @Gower and if there are more than one record with same `close` value as max?